# Stripe create payment method not working in react js

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am using React js and stripe ****Card Element**** to add a new card in my front end App. After I submit the card I am getting ****200**** success code and the response given below but I cant see my card in my ****Stripe developer dashboard****.

this is my js code

```
 const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
        type: 'card',
        card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
        billing_details: {
            address: {
                city: 'Anytown',
                country: 'US',
                line1: '1234 Main street',
                line2: '1234 Main street',
                postal_code: '123456',
                state: 'New York'
            },
            email: 'testuser2@test.com',
            name: 'test user 2'
        }
    })
```

This is the response with http code ****200****

```
{"id": "pm_1Lk9...........", "object": "payment_method", "billing_details": { "address": { "city": null, "country": null, "line1": null, "line2": null, "postal_code": "12121", "state": null }, "email": "testuser2@test.com", "name": "test user 2", "phone": null }, "card": { "brand": "visa", "checks": { "address_line1_check": null, "address_postal_code_check": null, "cvc_check": null }, "country": "US", "exp_month": 2, "exp_year": 2023, "funding": "credit", "generated_from": null, "last4": "4242", "networks": { "available": [ "visa" ], "preferred": null }, "three_d_secure_usage": { "supported": true }, "wallet": null }, "created": 166....., "customer": null, "livemode": false, "type": "card" }
```

I tried with curl command in the terminal referring [this](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create) but didn't work it for me

Comment: Do you attach this Payment Method to a Customer at all? I believe the way Stripe's dashboard works is that there is not dedicated view for Payment Methods - you'd get details about the Payment Method on the objects that are linked to it (like a Customer if you chose to attach the PM to it, or the Payment Intent/Charge). Try attaching the Payment Method to a Customer and see if you are able to find it them

Comment: @karbi yes you are correct, should attach the PM to a customer using attach method. I think this is available for the API side only and cant do it in the front end. anyway thank you very much.